# is there a way to link equal type definitions together?

Tags: xsd, schema

example code:

```
<xsd:element name="a">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="|(([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/([0-9]|1[12])/[0-9]{1,4})"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="b">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="|(([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/([0-9]|1[12])/[0-9]{1,4})"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

Now the type definition of element a and b are the same. is there a way to "link" those types together so that i do not have to repeat the typing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "link those types together". Can you be more specific?

Comment: @forty-two heys take a look at the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see. The easiest way to go is to create a named type:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="PatternType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="|(([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/([0-9]|1[12])/[0-9]{1,4})" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:element name="a" type="tns:PatternType" />
<xsd:element name="b" type="tns:PatternType" />
```

where `tns` is a prefix for your schema target namespace

Comment: thx. btw since you said the "easiest way to go", what's the alternative?